# not None test in Python

Tags: python, nonetype

Out of these not None tests.

```
if val != None:

if not (val is None):

if val is not None:
```

Which one is preferable, and why?

Comment: How about ```if val:``` ?

Comment: That is not the same test! That `if` will be false if val is 0, "", [], 0.0. etc. as well as if it is None.

Answer (score 1322, accepted):

```
if val is not None:
    # ...
```

is the Pythonic idiom for testing that a variable is not set to `None`. This idiom has particular uses in the case of [declaring keyword functions with default parameters](https://web.archive.org/web/20201002220217/http://effbot.org/zone/default-values.htm). `is` tests identity in Python. Because there is one and only one instance of `None` present in a running Python script/program, `is` is the optimal test for this. As [Johnsyweb points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965104/not-none-test-in-python/3965165#3965165), this is discussed in [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) under "Programming Recommendations".

As for why this is preferred to

```
if not (val is None):
    # ...
```

this is simply part of the [Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): "Readability counts." Good Python is often close to good [pseudocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode).

Comment: also, "is not" has special semeantics created for this purpose (it's not a logical consequence of how expressions are constructed; "1 is (not None)" and "1 is not None" have two different outcomes.

Comment: "not None" returns True. Interesting.

Comment: @gotgenes Not always right. Eg: var = ''. If you run this code, it tests successfully for None. Hence, you are not able to test if the variable was set to None or an empty string.

Comment: @Ethan `val = ''; print(val is not None)` prints `True`, so what part do you find incorrect?

Comment: @gotgenes My intent was testing a variable if it's set explicitly to `None`. I want to differentiate between empty string and None. Eg use case: a routine initializing `val = None` and caller sends `''`.

Comment: Right, because "is not None" *is far more readable* that not (val is None).   Clearly it means that something is the opposite of nothing, as oppose to the inverse of something as nothing.   Much better.  Thanks!

Comment: As for why the ``val != None`` is not recommended: If ``val`` can be either ``None`` or a more complex thing, like a numpy array, it's not entirely clear whether this intends to be an element-wise comparison (e.g: ``arr>0 `` will produce a list of indices at which elements of arr are positive), so if you expect ``val`` to be either an array or ``None``, then ``arr is None`` is the safest way to test this. In fact, Python 2.7.6 generates a warning that ``arr != None`` will work element-wise in the future. ``arr is not None`` is also nicer to read.

Comment: "Because there is one and only one instance of `None` present in a running Python script/program, `is` is the optimal test for this". Does this make the case for `val is 0` or `val is 'a'`?

Comment: @nivk good question. Small integers and short strings are interned, so that would work. The problem is that it is value-dependent: `val = 'asdasdasgerefgereasdasdasidonefe fkefe';                                                                                                                                 val is 'asdasdasgerefgereasdasdasidonefe fkefe'` is False even though both strings are identical. More generally, the internment of the strings is implementation-dependent and depends on how the strings were defined: see `val = '50'` vs `val = str(50)`

Comment: Since no one has mentioned it. It's worth noting that `not` is case sensitive and hence `is Not != is not`.

Answer (score 148):

From, Programming Recommendations, [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with `is` or `is not`, never the equality operators.
>
> Also, beware of writing `if x` when you really mean `if x is not None` — e.g. when testing whether a variable or argument that defaults to None was set to some other value.  The other value might have a type (such as a container) that could be false in a boolean context!

PEP 8 is essential reading for any Python programmer.

Answer (score 39):

The best bet with these types of questions is to see exactly what python does. The [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) module is incredibly informative:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis("val != None")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (val)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              4 COMPARE_OP               3 (!=)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis("not (val is None)")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (val)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              4 COMPARE_OP               9 (is not)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis("val is not None")
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (val)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              4 COMPARE_OP               9 (is not)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

Notice that the last two cases reduce to the same sequence of operations, Python reads `not (val is None)` and uses the [`is not` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is-not). The first uses the [`!=` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons) when comparing with `None`.

As pointed out by other answers, using `!=` when comparing with `None` is a bad idea.

Comment: What is the difference betwen compare_op 9 and 3?

Comment: @evolvedmicrobe From the `dis doc` ([https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html)), `COMPARE_OP` performs the boolean operation corresponding to the tuple `dis.cmp_op = ('<', '<=', '==', '!=', '>', '>=', 'in', 'not in', 'is', 'is not', 'exception match', 'BAD')`. So `COMPARE_OP 9` performs `is not` and `COMPARE_OP 3` performs `!=`.

Answer (score 25):

Either of the latter two, since `val` could potentially be of a type that defines `__eq__()` to return true when passed `None`.

Comment: That's rather dastardly `__eq__()` behavior, and something I hadn't considered. Good answer for catching a corner case.