# Adding if or try except blok in python function

Tags: python-2.7

I got this question i'm a little unsure how to solve:

"There are a NoneType error when reproducing the code. The getaddressdata() returns a None value. This can be fixed by adding an if-statement in the getpricelist() to see if the data is None. Use a try except block to handle invalid data."

Have to fix this before my code can run.

my function / code you see here:

```
def getpricelist( ):
    l1=[]
    for line in file('addresslist.txt'):
        data=getaddressdata(line.strip( ),'Cambridge,MA')
        if data != 'None':
            l1.append(data)    

    return l1
```

Where do i make the try / except blok??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use pythonic idiom `is None` to check if the variable is of a `NoneType` or not:

```
data = getaddressdata(line.strip( ),'Cambridge,MA')
if data is not None:
    l1.append(data)
```

Also see:

- [not None test in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965104/not-none-test-in-python)
- [What is the difference between " is None " and " ==None "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257919/is-none-vs-none)

Hope that helps.

Comment: it worked.. but i get another error in another function.. but thx