# Python: split bytes with a hexadecimal delimiter

Tags: python, split, hex

I'm working with a couple of binary files and I want to parse UTF-8 strings that exist.

I currently have a function that takes the starting location of a file, then returns the string found:

```
def str_extract(file, start, size, delimiter = None, index = None):
   file.seek(start)
   if (delimiter != None and index != None):
       return file.read(size).explode('0x00000000')[index] #incorrect
   else:
       return file.read(size)
```

Some strings in the file are separated by `0x00 00 00 00`, is it possible to split these like PHP's explode? I'm new to Python so any pointers on code improvements are welcome.

Sample file:

`48 00 65 00 6C 00 6C 00 6F 00 20 00 57 00 6F 00 72 00 6C 00 64 00 | 00 00 00 00 | 31 00 32 00 33 00` which is `Hello World123`, I've noted the `00 00 00 00` separator by enclosing it with `|` bars.

So:

```
str_extract(file, 0x00, 0x20, 0x00000000, 0) => 'Hello World'
```

Similarly:

```
str_extract(file, 0x00, 0x20, 0x00000000, 1) => '123'
```

Comment: `split` is the equivalent function to PHP's `explode`. Are you splitting based on an _actual string_ of `0x00000000` or are you checking for actual zero bytes in your file?

Comment: @figs Checking for actual sequence of 4 zeros. I've put up an example to illustrate my point.

Comment: So what are the `|` characters in your file?

Comment: They're not actually in my file, just pipes I use to indicate a sequence of zeros for readability.

Comment: Is this in Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: Python 2, but I think I'm not afraid to learn a 3 solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to assume you are using Python 2 here, but write the code to work on both Python 2 and Python 3.

You have UTF-16 data, not UTF-8. You can read that as binary data and split on the four NUL bytes with the [`str.split()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
file.read(size).split(b'\x00' * 4)[index]
```

The resulting data is encoded as UTF-16 little-endian (you may or may not have omitted the [UTF-16 BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the start; you can decode the data with:

```
result.decode('utf-16-le')
```

This will however *fail* as we just cut off the text at that last NUL byte; Python splits on the first 4 NULs found, and won't skip that last NUL byte that is part of the text.

The better idea is to decode to Unicode first, *then* split on a Unicode double-NUL codepoint:

```
file.read(size).decode('utf-16-le').split(u'\x00' * 2)[index]
```

Putting this together as a function would be:

```
def str_extract(file, start, size, delimiter = None, index = None):
   file.seek(start)
   if (delimiter is not None and index is not None):
       delimiter = delimiter.decode('utf-16-le')  # or pass in Unicode
       return file.read(size).decode('utf-16-le').split(delimiter)[index]
   else:
       return file.read(size).decode('utf-16-le')

with open('filename', 'rb') as fobj:
    result = str_extract(fobj, 0, 0x20, b'\x00' * 4, 0)
```

If the file as a BOM at the start, consider opening the file as UTF-16 instead to start with:

```
import io

with io.open('filename', 'r', encoding='utf16') as fobj:
    # ....
```

and remove the explicit decoding.

Python 2 demo:

```
>>> from io import BytesIO
>>> data = b'H\x00e\x00l\x00l\x00o\x00 \x00W\x00o\x00r\x00l\x00d\x00\x00\x00\x00\x001\x002\x003\x00'
>>> fobj = BytesIO(data)
>>> str_extract(fobj, 0, 0x20, '\x00' * 4, 0)
u'Hello World'
>>> str_extract(fobj, 0, 0x20, '\x00' * 4, 1)
u'123'
```

Comment: Reading up on BOM right now, how would I detect this? I prefer this way as it is cleaner than doing explicit decoding.

Comment: @VeraWang: your file would start with the bytes FF FE (encoding U+FEFF ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE to UTF-16 little-endian).

Comment: Sorry another question here: these files contain characters in English, German, French, Japanese and can also contain stuff not in the string. Does Python have a predetermined hex range for these set of characters? I only want "readable" characters if that makes sense.

Comment: @VeraWang: no, that doesn't make much sense. :-) Do you mean you want to filter on *printable* characters? Tabs, newlines, non-breaking spaces, etc, all carry meaning, you'll have to be more specific.

Comment: Yes, sorry it's been a long day :-). Including null bytes as well.

Comment: @VeraWang: you can use `str.translate()` to efficiently remove certain codepoints; `result.translate({0: None})` tells the method to map the `0` codepoint (a NUL) to `None`, which means *delete it*.

Comment: @VeraWang: alternatively, have the dictionary (whose keys must be integers, denoting Unicode codepoints) map to other codepoints (so again an integer, but a single Unicode character is fine too) to replace codepoints with other codepoints. So `result.translate({0: u'?'})` would replace NUL characters with a question mark.

Comment: Thanks, I've learnt quite a bit about Python from this post alone!

Answer (score 1):

First you need to open the file in [binary mode](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Then you `split` the `str` (or `bytes`, dependend on the version of Python) with a delimiter of four zero bytes `b'\0\0\0\0'`:

```
def str_extract(file, start, size, delimiter = None, index = None):
   file.seek(start)
   if (delimiter is not None and index is not None):
       return file.read(size).split(delimiter)[index]
   else:
       return file.read(size)
```

Furthermore you need to handle the encoding, since `str_extract` only returns the binary data and your test data is in UTF-16 little endian like [Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) noted:

```
>>> str_extract(file, 0x00, 0x20, b'\0\0\0\0', 0).decode('utf-16-le')
u'Hello World'
```

Besides: test with [`is not None`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965129/3385212) for a variable not to be `None`.

Comment: Not quite `'Hello World'`; more like `'H\x00e\x00l\x00l\x00o\x00 \x00W\x00o\x00r\x00l\x00d'`, which is UTF-16 little endian data.