# What is the most pythonic way to check if multiple variables are not None?

Tags: python

If I have a construct like this:

```
def foo():
    a=None
    b=None
    c=None

    #...loop over a config file or command line options...

    if a is not None and b is not None and c is not None:
        doSomething(a,b,c)
    else:
        print "A config parameter is missing..."
```

What is the preferred syntax in python to check if all variables are set to useful values?  Is it as I have written, or another better way?

This is different from this question:
[not None test in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965104/not-none-test-in-python) ... I am looking for the preferred method for checking if many conditions are not None.  The option I have typed seems very long and non-pythonic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [not None test in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965104/not-none-test-in-python)

Comment: I am checking for four variables and was, as well, thinking the obvious solution you posted is not very pythonic. I am sad having to conclude from the lack of answers that there doesn't seem to be a "nicer" way.

Comment: @schwobaseggl: No, this is not a duplicate as the question is not about how to check for None. It is about how to make it "look more pythonic" when checking multiple variables but not as many to rectify the proposed solution by Daniel Roseman.

Comment: def all_is_not_None(*args): return all(x is not None for x in args)

Answer (score 126, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the way you're doing it.

If you have a *lot* of variables, you could put them in a list and use `all`:

```
if all(v is not None for v in [A, B, C, D, E]):
```

Answer (score 176):

It can be done much simpler, really

```
if None not in (a, b, c, d):
    pass
```

UPDATE:

As slashCoder has correctly remarked, the code above implicitly does a == None, b == None, etc. This practice is frowned upon. The equality operator can be overloaded and not None can become equal to None. You may say that it never happens. Well it does not, until it does. So, to be on the safe side, if you want to check that none of the objects are None you may use this approach

```
if not [x for x in (a, b, c, d) if x is None]:
    pass
```

It is a bit slower and less expressive, but it is still rather fast and short.

Comment: Yes! And it's 10 times faster too! (According to `timeit`)

Comment: The problem with this is that the `in` and `not in` operators do equality checks against each element of the collection, which is advised against in PEP8.

Comment: Please be aware this is a Yoda Condition(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) and must be used with caution.

Comment: @Chandrahas Aroori: Hrrmmm. Exercise the caution you must!

Comment: In Pandas/Dask this yields: `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()` [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous)

Comment: @gies0r: Could you provide relevant code, please? I am very curious, because I have tried to substitute tuple with pandas Series (s = pd.Series((1, 2, 3, None), dtype=object)) and I didn't get ValueError. Although the first approach gave the wrong result, which is exactly what slashCoder warned about. 


Anyway, all this was meant exclusively for the affirming of None absence in primitive sequences like tuples and lists. In pandas you have isna(), so (not s.isna().any()) is more idiomatic and may be even faster approach.

Comment: Checking for object identity, using a set: `id(None) in {id(_) for _ in (a, b, c, d)}`.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel. Cool! But comparing ids is not very Pythonic, is it? Also, maybe using a list instead of a set is more efficient for not that large original iterable (a, b, c, d)?

Comment: Not very :) And of course when performance is critical, always profile for your specific use case / distribution of use cases.

Comment: Regarding Pandas/Dask (also Numpy): questions about this are very frequently asked, but the advice is fragmented by use case. The underlying principle is: because operators are broadcast across arrays, including `==`, when the array is compared to an element of the list or set you get an array of elementwise comparison results - and the library guards against converting that to bool (using it in an `if` comparison). For the current context: that implicitly prevents stuff like `in` from working.

Comment: I'll use this inspite "it doesn't happen, until it happens".

Answer (score 18):

I know this is an old question, but I wanted to add an answer which I believe is better.

If all elements which have to be checked are hashable, you could use a set instead of a list or tuple.

```
>>> None not in {1, 84, 'String', (6, 'Tuple'), 3}
```

This is much faster than the methods in the other answers.

```
$ python3 -m timeit "all(v is not None for v in [1, 84, 'String', (6, 'Tuple'), 3])"
200000 loops, best of 5: 999 nsec per loop

$ python3 -m timeit "None not in [1, 84, 'String', (6, 'Tuple'), 3]"
2000000 loops, best of 5: 184 nsec per loop

$ python3 -m timeit "None not in (1, 84, 'String', (6, 'Tuple'), 3)"
2000000 loops, best of 5: 184 nsec per loop

python3 -m timeit "None not in {1, 84, 'String', (6, 'Tuple'), 3}"
5000000 loops, best of 5: 48.6 nsec per loop
```

Another advantage of this method is that it gives you the correct answer even if someone defines the `__eq__` method of a class to always return `True`. (Of course, if they define the `__hash__` method to `return hash(None)`, this method won't work. But nobody should do that, because it would defeat the purpose of defining a hash.)

```
class Int(int):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(super())

print(all(v is not None for v in [1, Int(6), 2])) # True (correct)
print(None not in [1, Int(6), 2])                 # False (wrong)
print(None not in (1, Int(6), 2))                 # False (wrong)
print(None not in {1, Int(6), 2})                 # True (correct)
```

Comment: why is dict faster than list and tuple?

Comment: @zheyuanWang To check whether an an item is present in a list, the item is compared with each element of the list. That is `O(n)`. In case of a set, however, Python simply computes the hash of the item, and checks whether the set has a valid entry for said hash. This is `O(1)`.

Answer (score 8):

EDIT:
As noted by [Mo2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2124252/mo2), **this solution will fail** if any variable is set to `0` and `0` is considered a 'useful' value.

For the specific case presented by the OP

```
if not all([a, b, c])
```

will be enough.

```
all([a, b, c])
```

evaluates to False if any parameter is missing.

Comment: This isn't a good solution because values like `0` are evaluated to False.