# Check if value is not none before comparison

Tags: python, nonetype

I'm doing a bunch of operations that are basically:

```
if ((x is not None) and (y is not None)) and x > y:
    do_something
```

I'm doing this operation on every row of a data table where some of the values are null. Is there a more pythonic way of going about this, without have to check for None each time?

Comment: I dont't see how this could be imporved. However if instead of `x` and `y` are going to use large expression you could split this condition into different if-conditions firstly checking for `None` and then comparing `x` and `y`

Comment: you do know where x and y come from right? then you also know if None check is needed or not

Comment: Perhaps: `if not None in (x, y) and x > y:`.  This form can easily be extended to even more variables.

Comment: Take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42360956/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-check-if-multiple-variables-are-not-none

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
if not None in (x, y) and x > y:
    do_something()
```

Answer (score 3):

The parentheses are not needed, and `None` must be capitalized. Otherwise this is basically a good way to do it. Your data table might offer a way of filtering out all rows with `None` values at once, which would be an improvement.

Comment: Thanks, I tend to over use parentheses in my conditionals, I'll streamline it a bit going forward though.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a 'better' way to do it, however if you want to do it in one short line and make it more idiomatic, you could use:

```
do_something() if x is not None and y is not None and (x>y) else do_something_else()
```

Comment: @DarrylG thank you, I just learned a new thing that this code doesn't take zero inot account, edited the answer accordingly. Now it works for 0, -1