# None Test for Array in Python

Tags: python

I have a python array that may or may not be `None`:

```
    arr = None # or possibly an array

    x = arr == None

    if x: 
      # do something
```

And it works for cases in which `arr = None`, but if it is an array, I calculate the indices of the array which equal `None`, instead.

What is the expression which will evaluate to true if some entity in python is, as a whole, `== None`?

Comment: What does calculate_array_obj do? Checking for None is done as `if x is  None`

Comment: @Norrius and that is the answer to my question, so why is providing out-of-scope information important?

Comment: So was your actual question “how to compare to None in Python”? Sorry, it wasn't obvious straight away. I figure it is indeed irrelevant then.

Comment: Well, that's why we need the context: to figure out what you really needed!

Comment: @Norrius guess you answered on your first comment, so I don't understand what you mean

Comment: @bordeo to be fair, I don't see Norrius's comments as being hostile or anti-stack overflow rant, your question wasn't very clear, and they were asking for clarification. In no way did they put you or your question down.. It seems like you are the one being hostile right now...

Comment: If you want to make your questions more clear, take a look at how you can make a [mcve], as well as check out the [help] to improve in the future!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [not None test in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965104/not-none-test-in-python)

Comment: @MooingRawr I see it as the beginnings of one, followed by the Minimal, Complete and Verifiable thump. 

Which just happened.  And yet I already have a great, high quality answer below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should be sufficient

```
if x is None
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand corretly, your array is a `numpy` array, or any other data type that implements `__eq__` to return something other than a single `bool`.

```
In [1]: array = None

In [2]: array == None
Out[2]: True

In [3]: array = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

In [4]: array == None
Out[4]: array([False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

In this case, you can still use `is None`, which is the preferred way to check whether something is `None` anyway:

```
In [5]: array is None
Out[5]: False
```

Some other options would be to *not* initialize the array as `None` in **init** and use `hasattr` to check whether the array has already been properly defined, or just `try` to access the array and create it in case of an exception. However, using `is None` or `is not None` is probably the best way.