# Python 3.6 - 'NoneType' test fails

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am reading from an `sqlite3` database and filtering out `NoneType`, since I only want values which are **not** `None`. I tried both methods suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965104/not-none-test-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1), with identical results. This leads me to think that the below if-statement is correct, but I am missing something more fundamental. Any suggestions are appreciated.

### Reading from Databse

```
        conn.commit()
        c.execute("SELECT tact FROM LineOEE03 ORDER BY tact DESC LIMIT 1")
        current_tact = c.fetchone()
```

### NoneType test

```
        if current_tact is not None:
            current_tact = int(current_tact[0])
        else:
            current_tact = 60
```

### Error

> ```
> current_tact = int(current_tact[0])
> ```
>
> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'

- Why am I getting this error if I am specifically tageting `not None` types in my `if-statement`?
- What is the correct way to do this, such when the value is `None` I can assign a pre-defined value?

Comment: is `current_tact = [None]` (or a list/tuple containing `None` as first element)?

Comment: Seems like None exists inside current_tact.

Comment: Try `print(current_tact)` and you'll immediately see the problem.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist, absolutely right. Output is:`(None,)` Thanks for guiding me in the right direction Aran-Fey, very basic mistake from my end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either add an additional test to check if the first item in the list is not `None`, which is what you're actually trying to convert to an integer:

```
if current_tact is not None and current_tact[0] is not None:
    current_tact = int(current_tact[0])
```

or use a `try-except` block to avoid having to test at all:

```
try:
    current_tact = int(current_tact[0])
except TypeError:
    current_tact = 60
```