# What's the proper way to evaluate a variable having a value?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a class of variables that are being assigned `None` at instantiation. I've manually hardcoded data assignments to some of these variables, and am trying to evaluate whether or not they exist.

So basically I've set `my_class.first_col = 4`. The instantiation part looks essentially like:

```
def __init__(self):
  self.first_col = None
```

When I run this with the manual set to 4: `print(my_class.first_col == True)` it returns `False`. What's the proper way to see if that variable is assigned to something other than `None`?

Comment: How about `my_class.first_col is not None` ?

Comment: Yeah I saw that option per this question after I posted, and it fixed the problem. Still unsure why `first_col == True` doesn't work though. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965104/not-none-test-in-python

Comment: You assigned it the value 4? That's not True.

Comment: Then what is True? With your comment, I realized I assumed every object or variable was True, but I guess not