# Calling constructor of class as default argument in other class constructor

Tags: python, constructor, initialization, default-constructor, default-arguments

#### problem

I tried to call the constructor of a class inside another class' constructor's parameter's default assignment, but I encountered this problem where the constructor isn't called correctly. What is happening here?

#### code explanation

The `Bad` class is the case that doesn't work and the `Good` class is an ugly work around to solve the problem. The value `Base.i` is incremented for every time the constructor `Base.__init__` is called, and as can be seen, it isn't incremented correctly for the `o2` object, but it seems to be incremented correctly for each of `o1`, `o3` and `o4`.

#### code

```
class Base:
    i = 0
    def __init__(self):
        Base.i += 1
        self.i = Base.i

class Bad:
    def __init__(self, base = Base()):
        self.base = base

class Good:
    def __init__(self, base = None):
        if base is None:
            self.base = Base()
        else:
            self.base = base

if __name__ == "__main__":
    o1 = Bad()
    o2 = Bad()

    print("Bad:")
    print(f"o1.i: {o1.base.i}")
    print(f"o2.i: {o2.base.i}")

    o3 = Good()
    o4 = Good()

    print("Good:")
    print(f"o3.i: {o3.base.i}")
    print(f"o4.i: {o4.base.i}")
```

#### output

```
o1.i: 1
o2.i: 1
Good:
o3.i: 2
o4.i: 3
```

Comment: When checking for None, use: if base is None as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965104/not-none-test-in-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Default arguments are evaluated at *definition time*, so here

```
class Bad:
    def __init__(self, base = Base()):
        self.base = base
```

the name `base` (and hence `self.base`) is assigned an instance of `Base` at the time of definition already.

One way is to use a default of `None`, as you already do in `class Good`

```
class Good:
    def __init__(self, base = None):
        if base is None:
            self.base = Base()
        else:
            self.base = base
```

You could also define the `__init__` of `Bad` like this:

```
class Bad:
    def __init__(self, base = Base):
        self.base = base()
```

which will assign an instance of `Base` when `Bad` is initialized, not at definition time, so each instance of `Bad` will have its own `Base`.

If you want to able to pass arguments to base, you'd have to add options

```
class Bad:
    def __init__(self, base = Base, base_args=(,), base_kwargs={}):
        self.base = base(*base_args, **base_kwargs)
```

but in that case the `None` way is simpler to use, since you can just pass the constructed instance directly.

Comment: That `self.base = base()` doesn't allow custom arguments like `Bad(Base())`.

Comment: Yes, in that case the `None` way if the way to go. I just wanted to show a solution in case all your passed classes have the same argument-less signature (unlikely). I think I have seen the `None` way of solving this quite often, so it's not a bad idea.

Comment: That's not what I'm doing. I'm trying to pass an argument to the `Bad` constructor. The `Good` class in my question allows it, but the solution with `self.base = base()` does not.

Comment: That's what I just said, in case you want to do that you have to use the `None` way. The latter only works if all your constructors take no arguments. Basically you already found the way to solve this yourself.

Comment: Ah I see, I must have misread your comment. I will accept this answer if nothing else comes up.